# How does one avoid a NullReferenceException in a foreach loop within a View when my model is null?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, foreach

I get a "NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code" error with the following code in my View when I pass in a null value via my controller.  There are situations where I want to pass in a null value, but I do not want an error thrown when this happens.  What should I change my code to?

Originally my code was:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.MyModelStuff)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Bla.Title)
        </td>
    <tr>
}
```

I have tried the following with no success:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.MyModelStuff.Where( item => item.MyModelStuff != null))
etc. . .
```

How do I change the code so that it will handle null without throwing an error?  I've read I may need to be returning an empty collection of my model (?), how would I go about doing that - if it is indeed the necessary thing to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If my understanding is correct your collection is null.

A collection should never be null, like you said you should return an empty collection instead  and prevent your collection to be corrupted not exposing the real collection:

```
public IList<Employee> Employees
{
    get; 
    private set;
}
```

And initialize your collection inside the constructor

```
this.Employees = new List<Employee>();
```

Answer (score 7):

Honestly, I think a `null` model is a poor choice.  But if you insist, just add an `if` check:

```
@if (Model != null) {
    foreach (var item in Model.MyModelStuff)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Bla.Title)
            </td>
        <tr>
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, that fixes it just fine.  What is a better solution - I am allowing users to view a list of their Courses (think of a school) - if they don't have courses their course list is null - what should I do in it's stead?

Comment: What about returning a valid (non-null) model, but instantiating `Model.MyModelStuff` to an **empty** list/enumerable, rather than a null one?  Then your view code simplifies nicely.