# C# Lambda expressions and @item syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda

I ran up against this error and I'm wondering if anyone can help explain why this is happening. 
I'm displaying a list of books in a view and everything is displaying properly from the model. However, this code below isn't working:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Books)
{
  .. (other unrelevant code is here)...
@{
<!-- Display icon based on the recommendation status -->     
if (item.Recommendation.recName == "Highly Recommended" || item.Recommendation.recName == "Recommended")
{
    <img src="~/Content/Images/check.png" alt="Recommended" title="This book is recommended."/>      
}

if (item.Recommendation.recName == "Parental Judgement")
{
    <img src="~/Content/Images/warning.png" alt="Parental Judgement" title="Parental Judgement required for this book."/>
}

if (item.Recommendation.recName == "NOT Recommended")
{
    <img src="~/Content/Images/stop.png" alt="Not Recommended" title="This book is NOT Recommended!"/>
}
}
.. (other unrelevant code is here)...
}
```

It should be pretty obvious from the code, but what I'm trying to do is display a different icon based on the recommendation status of each book. When I run that code, it gives me an error saying `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

This is a pretty standard type of error, but I'm confused because the object reference seems to be set, based on the fact that **this code** works properly and displays the proper value (such as Highly Recommended or Not recommended) for each book:
`@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Recommendation.recName)`

 

So to sum up my specific question: Why is the lambda expression in `modelItem => item...` working, while the other code for the *same exact model* isn't working?

And since I'm clearly missing an understanding of something here, let me ask the more general question for this: **When is it "legal" to use the `@item.property` syntax, and when will it result in an error (like I have above)?**

Comment: Where is `item` defined?  Can you show that code?  Also that lambda seems wrong, it'd expect `item = > item.Recommedation.recName`.

Comment: Have you sure `item.Recommendation.recName` exists? NRE means that each `item` or `Recommendation` part contains null value which can't be dereferenced (see NRE explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it).

Comment: @juharr I added in the beginning of the foreach loop.

Comment: Why was the question marked down? And @TetsuyaYamamoto I understand what a NRE is, but `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Recommendation.recName) ` works. Doesn't that mean that the `item` or `Recommendation` both truly exists properly?

Comment: Indeed, NRE in `foreach` loop maybe originated from `Model.Books` which trying to dereference null value, common way to avoid NRE is null-checking `Model` in first place, e.g. `@if (Model != null) { foreach (var item in Model.Books) { ... }}` and ensure action method returns collection which already initialized (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359319/how-does-one-avoid-a-nullreferenceexception-in-a-foreach-loop-within-a-view-when).

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I checked `@if (Model != null) { foreach (var item in Model.Books) { ... }}` and it's not null. It definitely returns the collection, which I knew already because I have plenty of other code which returns the collection from the model. All the code blocks work if they use Html.Helper methods, but this one uses straight @item.property and won't work.

Comment: I suspect it is because of your `@{`that you have immediately after your `@foreach()` statement. Eitherway, I don't suggest you do mix-and-matching, **go for one coding-style and keep it consistent**.

Comment: @Svek well there's actually HTML code in between there (which I removed for the sake of this post). If I take out that `@{ ... }`, then it displays the if-loop as plain text without evaluating it.

Comment: Well, even more so a reason not to enclose your HTML in a `@{}` block. My comment means to use `@if()` instead.

Comment: @Svek Let me clarify: The HTML is after the @foreach, in standard Razor syntax. I didn't put HTML inside my `@{}` block. But either way, I tried switching to `@if()` like you said, but it didn't make a difference. I appreciate  everyone's trying to help though!

Comment: @Sh306 I updated my answer.  I meant to go for the `item.Recommendation` type... I'm not with it today

Comment: I don't know the controller method looks like, but often `Model` returns null due to not passing strongly-typed collection with `return View(modelName)`. Note that `ViewBag.Model` is dynamic property, and potentially contains null value if model collection not returned properly. `Model.Books.Recommendation` probably uninitialized at this point and throwing NRE when dereferencing `recName`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Null Reference Exception

Based on your description, the evidence points to your `item.Recommendation` type causing the null reference exception. It appears (without providing us with more information) that it is likely **not** initialized. Which may explain why your `@Html.DisplayFor()` is working.

You should consider checking if it is `null` first.

```
if(item.Recommendation == null) throw new Exception(" Whoops! :) ");
```

or on the alternative you could do a [Safe Navigational / Null-conditional Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators)

```
item.Recommendation?.recName // which does the work for you inline.
```

---

### Side Note

I'm not a big fan of nesting / combining the use of `@{ }` razor code blocks inside other blocks. It can be difficult to read and usually a headache to debug.

```
@foreach ( ... )
{
    @{
        if( ... )
        {
            <html></html>
        }
    }
}
```

Versus

```
@{ var foo = null; } // appropriate for declaring variables, and clean blocks of code.

@foreach ( ... )
{
    @if( ... )
    {
        <html></html>
    }
}
```

Comment: The type is a string, so it didn't solve the issue. But I appreciate the tip about not the nesting the razor block. What you were saying makes a lot more sense now that it's written out with an example.

Comment: Yup, that did the trick! I got a Whoops :( but at least I know where to work from now. thank you Svek